# Trying to get the path to my child-theme via my functions.php

Tags: functions

I am calling a CSS script into a specific page in my theme like this:

```
function testimonial_style() {
  if ( is_page( 4087 ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'testimonial-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/testimonial.css' ); 
  }
} 

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testimonial_style');
```

And, this code finds the parent theme:

```
get_template_directory_uri().
```

What I would like to know and do is how do I pull the CSS from my child theme which is the active theme? I would rather place the CSS in there (so it is not overwritten when I update the parent theme)

I hope that makes sense...

My child theme is in the usual place, i.e.

```
/wp-content/themes
```

Thanks!

Ah! I think I answered it > you use this:

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` is the correct function to use.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/

Comment: Whoops, now I see you answered your own question...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, since WordPress 4.7 is to use `get_theme_file_uri()`:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'testimonial-css', get_theme_file_uri( '/css/testimonial.css' ) );
```